# After adding angular material theme Font size gone small. #issue

Tags: angular

I am using bootstrap as well as angular material in my project but after adding angular material theme in "angular.json" font gone small but when I remove them then again it works well but component doesn't work. such as :--

[after adding angular material theme : image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3N3U.png)

[Without angular material theme : image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVIiL.png)

you can see in image **"India Today"** have some problem but not in only that.

I have checked all possible way but still it's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can simply target that elements manually and over write it in the css. Just use your desired font size on that.

Make sure you use Id to call that element and write it in the last line of your style sheet.

Hope according to specificity rule that might work without affecting the existing styles

Comment: Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes ?
Due to this mat-typography class had added in index.html file,
this thing was creating problem, I had to remove that.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got that what was the problem, when I was installing @angular/material then I did this:

> Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes ?
> Set up browser animations for Angular Material? Yes

Due to this **mat-typography** class had added in index.html file, then after I reinstall @angular/material and on that time I didn't set up global Angular Material typography styles(No), and I also remove that **mat-typography** class from index.html file.
After then It worked well, Everything is going well now.

Thank you to all for your help....

Answer (score 0):

How big is this project you are working on? A couple of pages? If so, just fix it manually on a case by case basis and next time you start a project remember to add any libraries that interfere with the styling early on!

This is a common problem when adding styling libs late on in a project. The only possible quick fix is trying to change the order in which you import the libs but this may not be possible if some are imported in styles.scss and some are imported in angular.json

Another possible fix is trying to limit what you are importing to the bare bones of only what you need. This may reduce collisions.

If this requires a custom fix then what is being impacted? Is it only font size? If so, start by setting the default font size for the body in styles.scss:

```
body {
  font-size: 1rem !important; // important not recommended but if desperate you can use it to force your hand or, even better, increase the specificity of the rule
}
```

Hopefully this approach will fix most the problems and then you can fire fight the remaining issues.

Comment: Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes ?
Due to this mat-typography class had added in index.html file,
this thing was creating problem, I had to remove that.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting...